# Storing scripts

Tags: lua

I'm implementing Lua scripting engine in my c++ game engine and I was wondering what is the best way to store and execute Lua scripts. I have many scene nodes where each of them could have it's own script assigned. Is calling **lauL_dofile(...)** every frame for that specific script a viable option, or is there a better way? For example, is there a way to store already parsed scripts? I was looking at **luaL_loadfile** and **lua_pcall**. I thought I would load scripts with first one, and call them with second one when I need, but lua_pcall doesn't seem to have an unique id as a parameter, so how should I know which script to execute?

Comment: Usually, you want to call `luaL_loadfile` at initialization time, and `lua_pcall` when useful during running.

Comment: But how would I know which script to call? What parameter in lua_pcall indicates which script should be executed?

Comment: -1: I debated with myself about whether to -1 the question, since the answer can be summed up as "read the reference". At first, I decided not to, since the docs can be a bit confusing. Then I saw that the [docs for `lua_call`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_call) had a full-fledged example of how to execute a call exactly like Lua does. So obtuseness of the docs isn't an excuse in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use the Lua API, you need to become comfortable with the Lua stack. And one of the most important things you can learn to do is understanding how to read [the Lua API docs.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pcall) For every function, there is a notation on the right about exactly how it affects the stack (if it modifies the stack at all).

`luaL_loadfile` loads a file and pushes that file as a Lua function onto the stack. `lua_pcall` executes a function on the stack. But it has a number of caveats about how it does stuff.

The way calling functions through Lua works in terms of the stack is simple. You push the function you want to call. Then you push all of the arguments, in order, from first to last. Then you issue your call of that function. `lua_pcall` works in this way. This means that the location of the function to execute is *always* `nargs + 1`, relative to the top of the stack, where `nargs` is the number of arguments you're passing to the function.

Note that `lua_pcall` will *pop the function from the stack* (along with all of the arguments). If you just loaded the file, this will be the *only reference* to that function in Lua. Thus, you will not be able to execute the file again. You should duplicate the function before pushing its arguments onto the stack, using [`lua_pushvalue` to copy it](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pushvalue). You should probably stick it in the `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` table or something, so that it's value is preserved.

Comment: I don't see how reading documentation would have helped (have read it once), maybe after few times, probably, but at least your answer contained all the information I needed to look further into. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you usually call `luaL_loadfile` at initialization time. The loaded files usually define some [global] names (or fill some slots in some global table) as Lua functions. The [lua 5.2 documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4) gives an example (§4 `lua_call`) of how to call one of them. You'll do such calls (perhaps using `lua_pcall` or `lua_call`) at appropriate places of your application, by pushing appropriate things on the Lua stack.